# Magento2 : Add New columns in "Products in Category"

Tags: magento2, admin, category-products

I want to add new columns in Magento 2 admin category where product assign  to category with product details.

Please check below image for more details:
[image]

Here, I have tried to add column using xml file at this path:

> /vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/view/adminhtml/ui_component/merchandiser_product_listing.xml

But that custom column appear while click on add product at that time it's window column display there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @PhilippSander, If you have answer of this question then reply otherwise go ahead.. ;)